# How to get last 6 months for the current year in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Dynamically I want to generate last six months using Jquery **[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AXXGZ/61/)**

```
var str = "";
var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];

        for ( var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {

            var now = new Date();
            var date = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i));
            var datex = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

            str += "Date :"+datex+" | Month : " + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + "-" + date.getFullYear()+"\n";
        }
```

above code works fine if current date for a month is less than 30th, if current date is 31 then the above code generate duplicate month with irrelevant dates.

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @raghavendra: He *is* using a `Date` object. OP, you want to `setDate(1)` before you `setMonth`. Also, having `now` in the loop is a waste, it doesn't change - put `now` and `setDate` above the loop.

Comment: @Amadan i can use setDate(1) but  i want previous month with as same as current date value eg: if current date is  03-06-2015 then the above function should return 03-05-2015 fallowed by other previous months

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Your title says "last 6 *months*", which ignores dates. If you really want the dates one, two... six months ago, then you need to figure out what result you want for "one month before Mar-31".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for last paste 6 months from current month on words

```
var str = "<option value=''>---Select Month---</option>";

        var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];


        var varDate = new Date();
        var month = varDate.getMonth()+1;
        var currentDay = varDate.getDate();


        for ( var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {

            var now = new Date();
            now.setDate(1);
            var date = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i));
            var datex = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

            str += "<option value='"+datex+"'>" + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + "-" + date.getFullYear() + "</option>";
        }

        $(".monthlyErrorReports").html(str);
```

This is for number of days / dates of current and previous month

```
var fullMonthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];  

var dateObject = new Date();
var currentMonth = dateObject.getMonth();
var strDateList = "<option value=''></option>"+"<optgroup label='--"+fullMonthNames[currentMonth]+"--'>";
var noOfDatesInMonth = daysInMonth(currentMonth,dateObject.getFullYear());
var varNoOfDaysFlag = noOfDatesInMonth;
var varItterationBreakFlag = true;
var varNoOfItteCount = 0;
var varTotalDaysCount = noOfDatesInMonth;
var currentDate = ("0" + dateObject.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (currentMonth+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + dateObject.getFullYear();
var previousDay =  new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1));
    previousDay = ("0" + previousDay.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (previousDay.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + previousDay.getFullYear();

for(var i = 1; i <= noOfDatesInMonth ; i++){

    var dropdownValue = ("0" + i).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (currentMonth+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + dateObject.getFullYear();

    strDateList += "<option value='"+dropdownValue+"'>" +("0" + i).slice(-2)+"-"+ monthNames[currentMonth] + "-" + dateObject.getFullYear() + "</option>";

    ++varNoOfItteCount;

    if(varNoOfDaysFlag == i && varItterationBreakFlag){

        dateObject = new Date(dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() - 1));
        currentMonth = (dateObject.getMonth());
        noOfDatesInMonth = daysInMonth(currentMonth,dateObject.getFullYear());
        i = 0;
        varItterationBreakFlag = false;
        varTotalDaysCount += noOfDatesInMonth;
        strDateList += "</optgroup><optgroup label='--"+fullMonthNames[currentMonth]+"--'>";
    }

    if(varTotalDaysCount == varNoOfItteCount){
        noOfDatesInMonth = 0;
    }
}           

strDateList += "</optgroup>";   

$(".NoOfDateList").html(strDateList);
```